# Which type of list is used for android alarm time

Tags: android, android-listview

when the user have to set the alarm time on his phone (HTC for me), there is two listViews, one for hours and the other for minutes.

I would like to reuse this type of lists on my application but I don't know if this is possible or i have to create those lists manually?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you slukian, I am loking for the TimePicker, something like this http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_6ZWsj8oW5ek/THqsoHDf41I/AAAAAAAADMw/Ph14FjMTJjI/s400/android-pin.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`TimePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html).

Comment: Exactly @Felix, thank you soo much foor this answer. Is there a possibility to populate this timePicker list with something else (for example some strings) ?

Comment: No, you can't. Have a look at [`NumberPicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html), the widget used by `TimePicker`. You could probably copy [its source code](http://grepcode.com/search?query=android.widget.NumberPicker) and adapt it to work with a list of strings as well. That's a pretty advanced task, though.